# How to solve equation with multiple trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $x$:

$\arccos( \cos(x) y + z) = \arcsin( \sin(x) a+b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\cos x = \alpha$, so $\sin x = \sqrt{1 - \alpha^2}$.  Then take the $\cos (\cdot)$ of both sides and note that $\cos \left( \arcsin[q] \right) = \sqrt{1 - q^2}$.  Then you get a quartic equation in $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos^{-1}(\cos(x)y+z)=\sin^{-1}(\sin(x)a+b)$$
Taking Sine of both the sides,
$$\sin(\cos^{-1}(\cos(x)y+z))=\sin(\sin^{-1}(\sin(x)a+b))$$
$$\sin\left(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-(\cos(x)y+z)^2}\right)=\sin(x)a+b$$
$$\sqrt{1-(\cos(x)y+z)^2}=a\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}+b$$
$$1-(\cos(x)y+z)^2=\left(a\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}+b\right)^2$$
$$\left(1-(\cos(x)y+z)^2+a^2\cos^2(x)-a^2-b^2\right)^2=\left(2ab\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}\right)^2$$
$$\left((a^2-y^2)\cos^2(x)-2yz\cos(x)+1-z^2-a^2-b^2\right)^2=4a^2b^2-4a^2b^2\cos^2(x)$$
Thus, you get a quartic equation in terms of $\cos(x)$. Solve it to get value of $\cos x$

Comment: Ummm... what here wasn't in the previously posted accepted answer?

Comment: Well, you were expecting quadratic equation (before editing your answer) but that was wrong. It's a quartic equation that I showed. You later edited your answer. Am I right?

Comment: I was not expecting a quadratic, but indeed I mistyped just two letters, later corrected.

Comment: Anyway, I didn't know that it was your misunderstanding or mistyping before I answered this question. I saw statement of your earlier answer which was wrong.